# Disable Applet button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button

I would like to disable a button

```
<BUTTON name="Next Page" onClick="Next()" VALUE="NextPage">NextPage</button>
```

based on a javascript variable

```
var opening = 0;

function Next()
{
var currentdoc = viewONE.getDocIndex();
    if (currentdoc == 5)
    {
    **[DISABLE BUTTON]**
    }
```

what is the javascript code please?

Background information:
Simply browsing through documents using a next and previous buttons. on the first document i want the "previous" button greyed out and on the the last document i want the "next" button greyed out.

Appologise for any incorect terms, newb and never asked this type of question before.
you are welcome to correct my term in a constructive way... need to learn.

Comment: An applet is made using Java, not JavaScript, and is not related to what you are doing.  No need to include 4 lines of noise at the end of questions.  Leave out 'thanks' and sigs.

Answer (score 1):

Sam's solution is good and will disable the action of the button but won't disable it functionally.

You can disable the input button by changing changing the "disabled" attribute, but you really need to give your button a valid identifier first (I wouldn't even want to let jQuery select it by name due to the space).

jQuery would look something like this:

```
$('#yourbuttonid').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Regular Javascript would be the following:

```
document.getElementById('yourbuttonid').disabled = true;
```

[Here's an example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/anacef/2).

Comment: Thank you. your help was most helpfull

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is:

```
var opening = 0;

function Next()
{
    var currentdoc = viewONE.getDocIndex();
    if (currentdoc == 5)
    {
        return; //This will end the function immediately.
    }
}
```

In terms of greying out buttons, can you not add / remove classes to show different versions of the buttons? We would need more to see your html, and what you have tried so far to help further.

[Tutorial on return](http://www.golivecentral.com/pages/txttut/jstut/return.shtml)